# Docker containers run async

Tags: mysql, maven, docker, nginx

I need to develop docker in my application, i create docker image with maven-docker-plugin. After that I run sh script whit is here.

```
docker run --name app-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=app -d mysql
docker run --name app -p --link app-mysql:localhost -d app
docker run --name app-nginx -d -p 80:80 --link app:app  nginx
docker exec app-nginx rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
docker cp app:/default.conf default.conf
docker cp default.conf app-nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
docker restart app-nginx
```

But i have a problem. First mysql container runns good. Second, app container runns good. But nginx container throws error :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /app AS /app-nginx/app.
```

If i run this scrip with command

```
sleep 120
```

between the containers it setups normally, as i understand nginx container runs before app container finishes. Is there any way to run containers without sleep command as it is hardcoded. How can i figure if container finished successfully. Can you help me with solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use something like docker-compose for this. But you can still manage with your code. The key is not to start the container but create it first and then start it

```
docker run --name app-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=app -d mysql
docker run --name app -p --link app-mysql:localhost -d app
docker create --name app-nginx -d -p 80:80 --link app:app  nginx
docker cp app:/default.conf app-nginx:etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
docker start app-nginx
```

Also the `--link` is deprecated and should not be used. You should be using `docker network create` to create a network and then assign that network to your containers using `--net`. `docker-compose` does a lot of these things automatically for you and that's why it makes more sense to use that instead